# Why does netlogo count turtles on neighbours differently?

Tags: netlogo

When I run the following two lines I get different answers. Does anybody know why? The first gives the answer I want:

```
ask turtles[
    let tempcol [color] of self
    show count (turtles-on neighbors4) with [color = tempcol]]

ask turtles[
    set nextcolor [color] of self
    let tempcol [color] of self
    show count (turtles-on neighbors4) with [color = [color] of self]]
```

Comment: The mistake in the second line is adding 'of self' but I would have thought this would have been redundant code that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in that the issue is with the use of `self`- from the [dictionary entry](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/self.html) for that primitive:

> "self" is simple; it means "me". "myself" means "the agent who asked
>   me to do what I'm doing right now.

In short, you want `myself`in the second example. Currently, your second example is saying something like, "turtles, show the count of neighbor turtles whose color is the color of *themselves*" where you really want to say "turtles, show the count of neighbor turtles whose color is the color of *myself*." For a potentially clearer example, check out this setup:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 10 [
    set color red
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ] 
  ask n-of 3 turtles [
    set color blue
  ]
 reset-ticks 
end
```

This creates 7 red turtles and 3 blue turtles. Now, if you ask one of the blue turtles to show the count of of turtles with the same color as itself, we should expect it to return a value of 3. If you run that code using `self`, however, the value returned is 10- because **all** turtles have a color that is equal to the color of themselves:

```
to self-compare

  ask one-of turtles with [ color = blue ] [
    print "'[color] of self' example:"
    show count turtles with [ color = [color] of self ]
  ]

end
```

If you run the exact same code but use `myself`, it returns the answer we would expect:

```
to myself-compare

  ask one-of turtles with [ color = blue ] [
    print "'[color] of myself' example:"
    show count turtles with [ color = [color] of myself ]
  ] 

end
```

I would also point out that almost all of your `of self` statements are redundant-you should be able to take them all out (except for `[color = [color] of self]]` that you will be changing to a `myself` statement anyway) and have your code run as before.